# Find the total number of real solutions

Tags: functions

Let
$$f(x)=9^x-5^x-4^x-2\sqrt{20^x}$$
How to find the number of real solutions of the equation $f(x)=0$?
I tried this way:
At $x\to-\infty$ value of $f(x)$ is $0$. At $x\to\infty$ we have $f(x)\to\infty$. For $x=1$ value of $f(x)$ is $-4\sqrt5$. We can see that $f(x)<0$ for $x=1$, so this function crosses $x$-axis at least one time. It is obviously that one solution is $x=2$. Now, I need to find out if there is more than one solution. I tried using derivatives, but it is very hard to solve $f'(x)=0$. Is there any easy method to solve this?

Comment: $$5^x+4^x+2\sqrt{20^x}=(5^{\frac x2}+4^{\frac x2})^2$$

Answer (score 3):

$$9^x=\left(5^{\frac x2}+4^{\frac x2}\right)^2\implies 5^{\frac x2}+4^{\frac x2}=\pm9^{\frac x2}$$

But as  $$5^{\frac x2}+4^{\frac x2}=-9^{\frac x2}\iff5^{\frac x2}+4^{\frac x2}+9^{\frac x2}=0\text{ can not have a real solution}$$

$$\implies5^{\frac x2}+4^{\frac x2}=9^{\frac x2}$$

Consequently, 
$$f(x)=0\implies \left(\frac{\sqrt5}3\right)^x+\left(\frac23\right)^x=1$$

Now, $\displaystyle\frac23, \frac{\sqrt5}3<1\implies f(x)$ is decreasing